# SQL Query to update column values from different table

Tags: mysql, sql

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJjXY.png)

I have two tables A & B. The key to join both table is A.AccointID=B.ItemID, i want to update B.Value column to null and update the value from Table A if the ID matches.

TABLE A

```
    AccountID              Value
   -----------------------------------------
    11DHEC14               51326SVC1565_AG1          
    11DHEC14               51326HI1053_AG1        
    11DHEC14               51326HI2143_AG1
```

### TABLE B

```
 ITEM ID                 Value
   -------------------------------------------
    11DHEC14                51326_HI2143_AG1
    11DHEC14                513262143QQQ
```

**OUTPUT**

```
    ITEM ID         Value
   ----------------------------------------  
    11DHEC14        51326SVC1565_AG1
    11DHEC14        51326HI1053_AG1
    11DHEC14        51326_HI2143_AG1
```

I tried by joining the tables but am getting more rows, i have mentioned the output also for a reference. Kindly help!!

Comment: It could be one-to-many relationship giving you more rows. Consider to put some sample data here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply---i have mentioned the sample data here---Basically i want to update table B(Value column) from Table A(Value column) if Table B (ITEM ID) matches with 'N' of rows in Table A(Account ID).

Answer (score 0):

At First make a relationship between two tables and then update your columns. Although you have not specified which type of relationship you want between tables, you can optimize your result set through applying proper where condition.

```
update A
set B.Value = A.Value 
from A inner join B
on  A.AccountID = B.ItemID
where A.Value = '51326SVC1565_AG1' and B.Value = '51326_HI2143_AG1';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply---my requirement is, 
1. The no of rows in Table B should not increase if Table A(AccountID) < Table B(ITEM ID) if it matches
2. Table B has 3 rows with some date in value column, Table A has 2 or 1 rows in values column--then blindly i need make a Table B(value) column to NULL and then i need to update distinct(Table A.Value) data to table B.
I have mentioned the inputs and outputs for a reference.

The major problem is--since the many rows has same key value if join it works like X*Y, so the No of rows getting increased.

Comment: As i mentioned in answer part, if you are getting multiple row from table A because of joining, set condition in where clause such as  A.value = 51326SVC1565_AG1

Comment: Also specify, B.Value =  51326_HI2143_AG1 (or something else ); in where clause.

Comment: Hi---Its just a sample data for a post----My actual Table A has around 10K rows and Table B has 15K rows--- :(

Comment: Is there any way to update my Table B with a data from Table A without join a tables???

Comment: I think your Main problem is understanding join part, Try to learn join which will minimize your work load,  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm

Comment: If you don't want to make join then try this way,   update A
set B.Value = A.Value 
from A, B